# Divisible by 1000003? Easy, just multiply the last digit by 300001 and add!

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic

Given a prime `P` greater than `10`, your program or function must figure out its divisibility rule `x`, defined as the integer with smallest absolute value which yields a multiple of the original prime when multiplied by the last digit of the prime and added to the rest of the original prime.

### Example

Given an input `31`, the last digit is `1` and the rest of the number is `3`. Thus your program must find the integer `x` with minimum absolute value such that `1*x + 3` is a multiple of `31`. In this case, `x=-3` works, so the program or function would return `-3`.

Given an input `1000003`, the last digit is `3` and the rest of the number is `100000`. Thus your program would find `x=300001` because `3*300001+100000 = 1000003` which is a multiple of `1000003`.

### Mathematical Background

The value of `x` can be used as a divisibility test. If a number `N` is divisible by `P`, then adding `x` times the last digit of `N` to the rest of `N` will yield a multiple of `P` if and only if `N` is divisible by `P` in the first place.

For `P=11`, we get `x=-1`, which is equivalent to the well-known divisibility rule for `11`: a number is divisible by `11` alternating difference of its digits is divisible by `11`.

### Rules

- The output may be in any form that clearly encodes both the sign and value of the output.
- The input prime will be between 10 and 2^30.
- You do not need to handle if the input is not a prime or is not in the range.
- You do not need to handle if both `x` and `-x` are valid outputs (should not happen).
- Brute force is permitted, but more creative solutions are appreciated.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code **in each language** wins! Do not let answers in golfing languages discourage you from posting in other languages.

### Test Cases

```
Input   Output
11  -1
13  4
17  -5
19  2
23  7
29  3
31  -3
37  -11
41  -4
43  13
47  -14
53  16
59  6
61  -6
67  -20
71  -7
73  22
79  8
83  25
89  9
97  -29
101 -10
103 31
107 -32
109 11
113 34
127 -38
131 -13
1000003 300001
2000003 600001
2999999 300000
9999991 -999999
```

Comment: A useful simplification: we're looking for the smallest `x` in absolute value where `10*x-1` is divisible by the input.

Comment: Can anybody provide a hint why `(3 / (n % 5 * 2 - 5) * n + 1) / 10` and `(n % 5 * 2 - 5^2) * n / 10 + 1` are able to find a minimal absolute value for something like this? My first intuition would have been to calculate the least common multiple using the greatest common divisor calculated with Euclid's algorithm.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Given a number, you can remove the last digit, multiply it by a number `x`, add it on, and still get a number divisible by `n`. If we then multiply the new number by 10 and subtract the original number it still remains divisible by `n`. xnor's comment then follows from some algebra. The next step is to rearrange the formula so that it gives `x` in terms of `n`: x = `(k*n+1)/10`. We want the smallest absolute `x` so therefore we want the smallest absolute `k`, and this must be whichever one of `-3`, `-1`, `1` or `3` (depending on `n`'s last digit) that makes the division exact.

Answer (score 15):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>32</s> <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```js
f=
n=>(3/(n%5*2-5)*n+1)/10
```

```html
<input type=number min=1 oninput=o.textContent=this.value%5*(this.value%2)?f(this.value):``><pre id=o>
```

`3/(n%5*2-5)` would be written `9/n(mod -10)` if I had access to balanced modulo division. Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @EgorSkriptunoff

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by replacing `n=>((n%10*2%14-3)*n+1)/10` with `n=>(3/(n%5*2-5)*n+1)/10`

Comment: [This is a polyglot for .Net C#.](https://tio.run/##jZI/C8IwEMX3fopbhMS/TdNaS9VFcNLJwbnEIAG9gomCiJ@92uLq04NkyMu7/Lg840emvtjm6h0faXf3wZ7LyJwq72n7iIh8qIIzdKvdgbaVYyHbU6L1lc3ccRi@15IMLRpeLIWeCO5l/WSUyT4PlJyouGlvl52n21Y1@/pkx/uLC3bj2AojlJKy/K5qqOZQLZCawM4J9GrIrCFVCr0p9GaQago7T2HnHHpzOKscUs2gdwa9Bf7fGEcnxtmJ4dPqR/ISjKZ/oLWFA/jHlaIrOMCuPizP6Nm8AA)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Probably a near-miss polyglot for Java 8 too... oh wait, I see your answer now!

Comment: @Neil You're right. I usually post Java answers, so I was already working on a port of *xnor* when I saw your answer. Posted it either way as a boring port crediting you.

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 27 bytes

```python
lambda n:(n%5*2-5^2)*n/10+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7BboMwEETP2a/YSyWSkNa7tjGOxJ9UrUBtFCTiokAV9evpGOLL7JsZ2zv@zdefpMuleV@G9tZ9tZzORXrxBz35D90f0puYoyyPaz98s5xpNzX39vHZp/F3Lva0S2XX3Nqx6NNcTq/TOPSw4Y93ONw1zaVI@5JTydvQLSLMJyGxzI4kADxJZFZSWIEUsyWbW5Cci5DL6MihIZbc6jryGSvyuFFRlSuQnKmhkDFQQEWVAio11Rk81YBIcS1GEiN4zEAtW@xlAj5WaGR8LNjTYk/Nbo2tc9kizQdRFiF9YvXEuJ4tNbQRLm7DPw)

The operations are done left to right:  `(((n%5)*2)-5)^2`.

I used my arithmetic brute forcer to find the expression `n%5*2-5^2` to perform `{1:-1,3:3,2:-3,4:1}[k]`, taking the negative inverse of a residue mod 5 into the range `[-2..2]`.

Comment: Is this arithmetic brute forcer publicly available somewhere?

Comment: Is that the only expression it found or does it just print the first one of a given length? (`3/(n%5*2-5)` is the same length as `(n%5*2-5^2)`.)

Comment: @Lynn No, I might clean and up and post it when I have time.

Comment: @Neil It only found equivalents and `n%5*2-6^3`. I only looked up to the length though of the expression without parens, whereas `3/(n%5*2-5)` is two characters longer but saves on outer parens due to precedence. Searching expressions of this length should take a while. This use-case does suggest an option to only find expressions that can be used in a given context via their outermost operation having high enough precedence.

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <del>10</del> 8 bytes

```
,N⁵æiAÞḢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/H71Hj1sPLMh0Pz3u4Y9H///8NDUDAGAA)

#### Explanations

```
,N       Get [Input, -Input].
⁵æi      Modular inverse of 10 mod each of [Input, -Input].
AÞ       Sort by absolute value.
Ḣ        First.
```

Comment: +1 I have *never* seen a Jelly submission with register that actually saves bytes

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder It was because I didn't golf it well.

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 14 bytes

```
∧.ℤ≜×₁₀-₁;?%0∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1HHcr1HLUsedc45PP1RU@OjpgZdIGVtr2oAlPn/39DI/H8UAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>16</s> 9 bytes

*Saved way too many bytes thanks to an observation by @xnor*

```
_*AÉ vU}c
```

[Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=XypBySB2VX1j&input=MTAwMDAwMw==) May take a couple of seconds on larger inputs.

#### Explanation

```
_  *AÉ  vU}c    Implicit: U = input integer
Z{Z*A-1 vU}c    Ungolfed
Z{        }c    Loop through each integer Z in [0, -1, 1, -2, ...] and yield the first where
  Z*A             Z times 10
     -1           minus 1
        vU        is divisible by the input.
                Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <strike>69</strike> <strike>54</strike> 53 bytes

**Edit:** -15 bytes thanks to [@Mr.Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder)

**Edit:** -1 byte by using recursion

```python
f=lambda a,x=-1:(a%10*x+a/10)%a and f(a,-x-(x>0))or x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY/BDoMgEETP7VfsxURbTEFRxMT@SNMDjTEladEYD/Tr6SwHdnbfkFnYfsd7DU1Ky/Rx39fsyIk41WosXaHkJV7dTcmqAA4zLaUTdazLeJdVte4U04LqyQd6KCVItTgGxwpq0DfQFrwF01ANptF30A5eD9ZjNlADZsAG6AC1nCM5VHKqzCO4yksaHtu8MndsaC4ds45Zz/c4XZn8LHYHdm0uzPIOa5/j@bTtPhzkBf7oq/QH)

Comment: [54 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9E2M6@gtERD07rCVteQqzwjMydVI1HV0ECrQjtR39BAUzXRCihToatRYWegyVVQlJlXolDx/7@hIQA). I don't see why you have those variables when you only use them once

Comment: Yeah, was in a bit of a hurry when I wrote it

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>31 29</s> 27 bytes

```python
lambda n:3/(n%5*2-5)*n/10+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPylhfI0/VVMtI11RTK0/f0EDb8H9BUWZeiUKahqGhpg6QNAaT5mDSEkQaGWv@BwA)

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>23</s> 21 bytes

```
n->3/(n%5*2-5)*++n/10
```

Port of [*@Neil*'s JavaScript (ES6) answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139698/52210), but -2 bytes thanks to *@Nevay* due to implicit flooring of integers.

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##jVLBjoIwFLz7Fe9iUjQgUBGJ2f2D9eLReKgFTRUfRKrJxvDtWNCrGV/aJn2dzkybOam78qu64FN@7nSpmob@lOHHiMiwLa4HpQta99uhQVr0K3sr12nddKOxyhpNa2L6oY79XzkTPE4msZ94k@mUZ1HYrV7Q@rYvHfR9416ZnC5OTWzs1fBxuyPlvaQ2/40tLkF1s0HtjmzJggMtosgblD8DJAKkCJABQIwkYsQg0SskMjlHDHPEkCCTCySxQBIpYkjRT6bI5BIxLBFDBvMQwsyFMHQhshHh4MbQqcRO@4L5/Q6VDYW@d6i3r3bUdk8)

Comment: 21 bytes: `n->3/(n%5*2-5)*++n/10`

Comment: @Nevay Even when I create a port of the top answer, you still have to golf me.. xD (Read: Thanks and nice job!)

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 25 bytes

```
=.3/(MOD(A1,5)*2-5)*A1+.1
```

(Excel corrects to:

```
=0.3/(MOD(A1,5)*2-5)*A1+0.1
```

)

Comment: Actually I think you're allowed to claim the number of bytes you need to enter (but I'm too lazy to check meta).

Comment: @Neil yes - you are allowed to claim the number of bytes entered for google sheets, excel, and vba

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 bytes

*Inspired by [Neil's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139698/61613).*

```
Ì*2%E-3 *UÄ /A
```

[Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=zCoyJUUtMyAqVcQgL0E=&input=OTk5OTk5MQ==)

#### Explanation:

```
  Ì  *2%E-3 *UÄ  /A
((UgJ*2%E-3)*U+1)/A
  U                  // Implicit U = Input
   gJ                // Get the char at index -1 (last char)
     *2              // Multiply by 2
       %E            // Mod 14
         -3          // Minus 3
            *U+1     // Multiply by U+1
                 /A  // Divided by 10
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 12 bytes

```
3Q5%}5-f*hTf
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=3Q5%25%7D5-f%2ahTf&input=17&warnings=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 14 bytes

```
h/*x-y%QK5K2QT
```

**[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=h%2F%2ax-y%25QK5K2QT&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=11%0A13%0A17&debug=0)**

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 10 bytes

```
~IIT*tR%)h
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%7EIIT%2atR%25%29h&input=11&warnings=0)

```
~I         -   Integers
  I     )  -  filter(^, not v)
   T*t     -    ^ *10 -1
      R%   -   input % ^
         h - ^[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>44</s> 43 bytes

*(Crossed out 44 is still 44.)* Thanks to Fireflame241 for saving a byte!

```python
P=input();i=P/3
while i*10%P-1:i-=1
print i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8A2M6@gtERD0zrTNkDfmKs8IzMnVSFTy9BANUDX0CpT19aQq6AoM69EIfP/f0swMAQA)

There is exactly one number between `0` and `P-1` which is an inverse of `10`.  But if that inverse `u` happens to be greater than `P/2`, then `(u-P)` is also an inverse, and has a smaller absolute value than `u`.  So it turns out that we're really looking for the unique number `x` between `-P/2` and `P/2` which is an inverse of `10`.

The code above does exactly that, starting at (the floor of) `P/2`, and stepping
downward until an inverse is reached.  This must happen for some number greater than `-P/2` so long as `P` is a prime greater than `10`.  More precisely, it will terminate if and only if `P` is coprime to `10`.

**Edit:** It actually turns out that `x` is guaranteed to be between `-P/3` and `P/3`, so the current version starts at `P/3` and steps down from there.  See the section labeled **Improved Bound** for an explanation of this.

#### Mathematical explanation

It was not immediately obvious to me why the divisibility test worked.  Here's an explanation, in case anyone else was wondering.

Let `P` be a prime, greater than `10`, whose last digit is `b`.  Thus

`P = 10a + b`

where `a > 0`, and `0 <= b < 10`.  In fact `b` is either `1`, `3`, `7`, or `9`, because a prime greater than `10` must end in one of these digits.

Now suppose `bx + a = 0 (mod P)`.  Then

`a = -bx (mod P)`

`10a + b = 10(-bx) + b (mod P)`

`0 = 10(-bx) + b (mod P)`

`0 = b(1 - 10x) (mod P)`

Since `P` is prime, the integers `mod P` are an [integral domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain). So  either `b = 0 (mod P)`, or `1 - 10x = 0 (mod P)`.

We know `0 <= b < 10 < P`, so if `b = 0 (mod P)` then `b = 0`.  But we said `b` is either `1`, `3`, `7`, or `9`, so this is impossible.  Therefore `1 - 10x = 0 (mod P)`, so `10x = 1 (mod P)`.  In other words, `x` is the inverse of `10`, modulo `P`.

Now suppose `N` is a nonnegative integer whose last digit is `d`, so `N = 10c + d.`  We have a chain of equivalent statements:

`10c + d = 0 (mod P)`

`<==> 10xc + dx = 0 (mod P)`

`<==> c + dx = 0 (mod P)`

QED.

#### Usefulness?

I was also wondering whether the divisibility test (given `N = 10c + d`, replace `N` by `dx + c`) would actually be productive in practice.  Or at least, does it reliably replace `N` by a number smaller than `N` (in absolute value)?

Suppose `N = 10c + d`, where `c >= 0` and `0 <= d < 10`.  Therefore `10c = N - d <= N`.  By the triangle inequality,

`|c + dx| <= |c| + |dx| = c + d|x| <= N/10 + d|x|`

`< N/10 + 10|x| <= N/10 + 10P/2 = N/10 + 5P`

Thus if `5P <= 9N/10`, then `|c + dx| < N`.

In particular, if `N >= 6P`, then `|c + dx| < N`.  Thus, given `P` we begin by calculating `2P`, `3P`, ..., `6P`, along with `x`.  Then given `N`, we run the divisibility test repeatedly until we reach a number less than or equal to `6P`, and check whether the result is any of the numbers `0`, `P`, `2P`, ..., `6P`.

(Of course, whenever we reach a negative number, we replace it by its absolute value, which is fine since `q` is divisible by `P` if and only if `(-q)` is.)

#### Improved Bound

I noticed that `|x|/P` never seemed to be close to `1/2`.  In fact it seemed like it was always less than `1/3`...or upon closer examination, it was always very close to either `1/10` or `3/10`.  The biggest it ever got seemed to be `4/13` (which happens when `P=13` and `x=4`).  Why would this be?

Let `u` be an integer and suppose that `10u = kP + 1` for some integer `k`, so `u` is an inverse of `10`, modulo `P`.  Then we also know that `k` is relatively prime to `10`, since `k(-P)` is equivalent to `1` modulo `10`.

Now, we know that the inverses of `10` modulo `P` all differ by multiples of `P`, so we can take the integer `u` and either add or subtract multiples of `P` at will, and the result will always still be an inverse of `10` modulo `P`.  Suppose we choose to subtract `P` from `u`: we get

`10(u - P) = 10u - 10P = kP + 1 - 10P`

`10(u - P) = (k - 10)P + 1`

In other words, decreasing (respectively, increasing) `u` by `P` corresponds to decreasing (increasing) `k` by `10`.  We wish to add/subtract multiples of `P` from `u` until the left-hand side is minimized in absolute value; but the left-hand side is minimized exactly when the right-hand side is minimized, and so we want to add/subtract `10` from `k` until the right-hand side is minimized in absolute value.

But we know that this will happen when `k` is between `-5` and `5`, and therefore (since `k` is relatively prime to `10`) this means `k` is either `-3`, `-1`, `1`, or `3`.  (This is the content of @Neil's comment under the OP. **Thanks, Neil!**)

Thus when `|u|` is minimized (i.e., `u=x`), we'll have `x/P = u/P = k/10 + 1/(10P)`, where `k` is either `-3`, `-1`, `1`, or `3`.  Therefore `|x|/P <= 3/10 + 1/(10P)`.  Equivalently, `|x| <= (3P + 1)/10`.

Further, this inequality is strict at `P=11`, because at `P=11` we have `x=-1` and `k=-1`.  The smallest `P` for which equality holds is `P=13` (where `x=4` and `k=3`).

Therefore the largest that `|x|/P` ever gets is `3/10 + 1/(10*13)`, because `P=13` is the first prime for which we have `k=3`, and among those with `k=3`, the `1/(10P)` term is largest when `P` is smallest (i.e., at `P=13`).  Therefore, for all `P`, we also have `|x|/P <= 3/10 + 1/130 = 4/13 < 1/3`.  This explains why in the above code we can initialize at `i = P/3` rather than having to start at `P/2`.

Further, the bounds in the **Usefulness** section above can now be improved.

*Lemma*: Let `N = 10c + d` where `c > 0` and `0 <= d <= 9`.  Then `c + d|x| < N/10 + 9(3P + 1)/10`.  (Note the strict inequality.)

Proof of Lemma: by cases.  Case I: `d = 0`, so `N = 10c`.  Then `c + d|x| = c = N/10 < N/10 + 9(3P + 1)/10`.

Case II: `0 < d <= 9`.  Then `10c = N - d < N`, so `c < N/10`.  Therefore `c + d|x| < N/10 + d|x| <= N/10 + 9|x| <= N/10 + 9(3P + 1)/10`. QED.

Thus, if `N > 3P` (and `N = 10c + d` as before), then

`3P + 1 <= N`

`9(3P + 1)/10 <= 9N/10`

`N/10 + 9(3P + 1)/10 <= N`

`c + d|x| < N/10 + 9(3P + 1)/10 <= N`

So, if `N > 3P` then `c + d|x| < N`.

Therefore, we only have to find `P`, `2P` and `3P`, along with `x`.  Given `N > 0`, while `N > 3P`, we replace `N` by `|c + dx|`, which decreases `N`. Eventually we'll get `N <= 3P`; at that point we stop and check whether `N` is equal to any of the numbers `0`, `P`, `2P`, or `3P`.

We can't do better than `3P` in general. For example suppose `P = 13` and `N = 39`, so `x = 4`. Then replacing `N` by `dx + c = 9(4) + 3` leaves `N` unchanged.

Comment: Very nice explanation! You can save a byte by moving `-1` outside the parenthesis:  [43 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8A2M6@gtERD0zrTNkDfiKs8IzMnVcHQQCtTNUDX0CpT19aQq6AoM69EIfP/f0NzAA "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @fireflame241 Thank you very much!  I could claim that I left it at 44 just so I could cross it out (though this would be a lie).

Answer (score 1):

### [Whitespace](http://web.archive.org/web/20150623025348/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/), 92 bytes

Note that this language's syntax consists of *only whitespace*, so each whitespace character has been prefixed here with S, T, or L (corresponding to Space, Tab, and Linefeed, respectively). These can be removed without losing functionality, but they are included here in order to display it correctly.

```
S S S L
T   L
T   T   S S S L
T   T   T   S L
S S S S T   T   L
T   S S L
S L
T   S S S T S T L
T   S T T   S L
S T S S S S S S T   S T L
T   S S T   T   S T S S S S T   L
T   S S S S S S T   S T S L
T   S T S T L
S T L
L
L
.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgYuTi5MTTAMpLiBDgRMoAuQrgEgFTgUQDywF4sJFQEJgATAHKg7SApIGIi6u//8NDQE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
ḟȯ¦⁰←*10İ±
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcwhDsJAEEbh@5An9u@0nc45kARPQgiCEHQRaG6Aw1JcdYPgGvQiy9Y9873d@bTPh@NlzXzt8298fF/Tc@6H@XZfKX2G6Z1z3kjIkKOgMqrAhDm1qI3aaYwmaEXruHDDg87ogigqFZ/KIC0daJlVpU3bPw) A port of [ETHproductions' answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139694).